# Zend init database connexion on-demand

Tags: database, zend-framework, lazy-evaluation

In my current project, written using the Zf 1.13 (or something alike), i have pages that are getting a very high amount of hits (over 5k simultaneous connections).

I have set up Memecached to limit the amount of queries issued by these pages but my i now encounter another problem : They still are generating connexions to mysql, thus reaching the max_clients of mysql, even if no queries are issued.

So in my lighter Bootstrap, i have this piece of code

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory($cfgT['resources']['db']['adapter'], $cfgT['resources']['db']['params']);
$db->getConnection();
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
```

I'd like to know if i can move this piece of script out of the Bootsrap class, into the script in order to initialize a DB connection ONLY when i'm getting a cache miss?

Thanks for your help!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`Zend_Db` does this by default. However the `$db->getConnection()` call you have will trigger the database connection - if you remove this it should work as you want and connect when the first query is performed.